# What does this symbol mean in discrete mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm reading a discrete maths book, and I can't figure out what this symbol means (the one that looks like a triangle):

> If $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$ are propositions, explain why
> $$
> \bigwedge_{i=1}^{n-1}\bigwedge_{j=i+1}^n (\neg p_i \vee \neg p_j)
> $$
> is true if and only if at most one of $p_1,p_2\dots,p_n$ is true.

[(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bgte.png)

Comment: Read your text book; I ensure you that you can catch up.

Comment: That's not a triangle.  It depicts conjunctions of disjunctions.

Comment: Every book defines its symbols. Read carefully.

Comment: I read the whole chapter, now I'm in exercise number 44, but, to be honest, I don't see anything like that in the whole chapter, that's exactly why I can't figure out what this means.

Answer (score 2):

$\wedge$ is the logical `and` operator

$\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n$ is repeated applications of the logical `and` operator similar to how $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n$ is the symbol for repeated addition or $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n$ is the symbol for repeated unions.

$\vee$ is the logical `or` operator

$\neg$ is the logical negation operator

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know that it was a "big" operator, I did know that the conjunction was expressed in that way and that the disjunction was the inverse, but since I saw that it was a kind of summation I thought that perhaps it had another meaning.

Thank you very much.